Is FLAN-t5 a good MT model at this stage for baseline comparision?
I'm currently working on a research project which involves collecting some information about baselines of Machine Translation Tasks (preferably WMT '19, WMT '14 datasets), and wanted to get a broad view from the community about the applicability of FLaN-T5 model on the these datasets. Is FLaN-T5 a valid baseline to compare against for MT results? What are some SoTA models at this stage on WMT datasets that one must consider?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
